# What does <F6>q mean in ls command output?

Tags: rhel, ls, output

I used `ls ~` on RHEL 7 but I got `<F6>q` as output! What does it mean?

```
[user@server2 ~]$ ls /home/user/
<F6>q

[user@server2 ~]$ ll
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 340 Sep 18 17:16 <F6>q
[user@server2 ~]$ cat <F6>q
-bash: F6: No such file or directory
[user@server2 ~]$ touch test
[user@server2 ~]$ ls
<F6>q  test
[user@server2 ~]$ vim <F6>q
-bash: F6: No such file or directory
[user@server2 ~]$
```

Comment: undisplayable character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## It means that your file is named `<F6>q`.

These are *not* undisplayable characters, as comment-answers and other actual answers suggest.  You can see them displayed, right in front of you.  ☺

In any case, `<F6>` is not any of the forms that `ls` emits for undisplayable characters.

```
[user@server2 ~]$ cat <F6>q
-bash: F6: No such file or directory
[user@server2 ~]$ vim <F6>q
-bash: F6: No such file or directory
[user@server2 ~]$
```

You need to learn about shell syntax.

You are running the `cat` and `vim` commands with their standard inputs redirected from the file `F6` and their standard outputs redirected to the file `q`, with no actual command arguments.  The former redirection fails, because there is no file named `F6`, your file rather being named `<F6>q`, and the latter redirection is consequently not attempted at all.

Here is the same command, with whitespace showing how the shell is parsing it:

```
[user@server2 ~]$ cat < F6 > q
-bash: F6: No such file or directory
[user@server2 ~]$ vim < F6 > q
-bash: F6: No such file or directory
[user@server2 ~]$
```

To pass a file name containing shell metacharacters to a command as-is, without the shell responding to the metacharacters, they must be *quoted*:

```
vim '<F6>q'
```

or *escaped*:

```
vim \<F6\>q
```

Given what happens in VIM when you press a function key in `ex` command input mode, it is fairly easy to accidentally generate files with names like these using VIM.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using plain `ls` (or its alias `ll`) and the output is going to a terminal, RHEL 7 `ls` will convert control characters and other non-printable characters into a visible form. That's most likely what you're seeing. If the output is going to anything other than a terminal, this default replacement won't happen.

You can use `ls -q` to replace non-printable characters with question marks. Question mark is an appropriate shell wildcard for a single characters, so if you run `ls -q /home/user/` and see `?q` as a response, it means your mystery file probably has an unprintable character with ASCII value of 0xF6 as its first character.

You can also use `ls -b` to get non-printable characters represented as C-style escape codes, which may not be directly usable in a shell, but allows exact identification of each unprintable character.

You'll probably want to rename the file into something easier to handle:

```
cd /home/user
mv ?q possible-typo
```

It might have been created as a result of mistyping the `vi` command `:wq` as `:w<extra character>q`. The latter form of the command is interpreted as "save the current file using name `<extra character>q`" instead of "save using the existing name and then quit".